# Load limit of Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: usb, power

After connecting Android phone to Pi 2 though USB the red and green light are very low. Does Pi 2 have any energy load limit?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, but I have a pretty weenie phone.  I don't think you could damage it this way, although if it is drawing too much power it may brown out under load -- dunno how susceptible the pi 2 is to that.  **What size is your power supply in amps?**

Comment: 1500mA (the phone charger for now xD - sony xperia z1)

Comment: Presuming that matches what the phone might draw, it is probably not enough for both of them...if you can turn off charging on the phone, try that.  Or a bigger supply, of course.  If you know someone with an ipad those have 2.1 A chargers.  Powered hubs are usually unregulated, that might work if you have a beefy enough one kicking around.

Comment: I read something about the power supply for Pi and about microusb - microusb can handle max 1.1A. I really bad in these things. After I connected an old android device (an old samsung) the lights wasn't so low like after connecting Z1. I think the smartphone use more power than RPi can handle. Thank You for Your response!

Comment: I don't think there's a 1.1A limit on the microUSB.  But the pi 2 itself probably draws ~700 mA.  That phone will probably suck at least 1A, so the 1.5 A total is a little too little.

Comment: There are several possible issues. The Pi will only supply 600mA (although this can be increased to 1200). Many phone chargers are unsuited for running the Pi as voltage may drop as low as 3.6V (this is OK for a "charger", and in spec). It also raises the question of what you expect the phone to do.

Answer (score 2):

The RPi 2 is very power hungry.

I had a 2.4Ghz keyboard/mouse dongle, and wifi inserted. I plugged in another silly 5v gizmo (fan) and it failed to provide it enough power to get up to speed. When all other devices had been removed the fan got full power.

I'd expect the Phone draw to be even greater, thus you'd end up under powering the Pi.

This is using Adafruit's 5v/2amp microUSB adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I went with a powered USB Hub to take the load off of the pi2 power supply and it is now stable as a table.

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct.

Comment: How do I "mark an answer as correct"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. Each USB port has a limit, wit ha polyfuse before it. The Raspberry Pi itself can only take a max of 5V 1.x Amps. I'd recommend a powered USB hub.